# How to understand nil vs. empty vs. blank in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I find myself repeatedly looking for a clear definition of the differences of `nil?`, `blank?`, and `empty?` in Ruby on Rails.  Here's the closest I've come:

- `blank?` objects are false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, `""`, `" "`, `nil`, `[]`, and `{}` are blank.
- `nil?` objects are instances of NilClass.
- `empty?` objects are class-specific, and the definition varies from class to class. A string is empty if it has no characters, and an array is empty if it contains no items.

Is there anything missing, or a tighter comparison that can be made?

Comment: One gotcha is an empty array returns false for `present?`. Which is because `blank?` returns true for an empty array.

Comment: One nice thing is to see that `:nil?` is defined on `::Kernel` and overridden on `::NilClass`, while `:empty?` is implemented separately on many classes (natively on `::String`, `::Array`, `::Hash`, and non-natively on other classes like `::Set` from stdlib and `::ActiveRecord::Relation` from rails). So `:nil?` is available in all subclasses of `::Object` and also in every class that includes `::Kernel` by itself, where `:empty?` must be implemented or included specifically in your classes.

Comment: If you try to understand the whole `nil` concept [start here](https://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/ruby-is-nil/).

Comment: ```[1] pry(main)> [].blank?
=> true```

Answer (score 1493, accepted):

`.nil?` can be used on any object and is true if the object is nil.

`.empty?` can be used on strings, arrays and hashes and returns true if:

- String length == 0
- Array length == 0
- Hash length == 0

Running `.empty?` on something that is nil will throw a `NoMethodError`.

That is where `.blank?` comes in. It is [implemented by Rails](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F) and will operate on any object as well as work like `.empty?` on strings, arrays and hashes.

```
nil.blank? == true
false.blank? == true
[].blank? == true
{}.blank? == true
"".blank? == true
5.blank? == false
0.blank? == false
```

`.blank?` also evaluates true on strings which are non-empty but contain only whitespace:

```
"  ".blank? == true
"  ".empty? == false
```

[Rails also provides](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) `.present?`, which returns the negation of `.blank?`.

Array gotcha: `blank?` will return `false` even if all *elements* of an array are blank. To determine blankness in this case, use `all?` with `blank?`, for example:

```
[ nil, '' ].blank? == false
[ nil, '' ].all? &:blank? == true
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, some non-empty strings count as blank.

Comment: Why haven't they overwritter nil's .empty? if they could add .blank?

Comment: Also:
`false.blank? == true`

Comment: is `nil.blank?` something added by Rails? In `1.9.3p194` I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'blank?' for nil:NilClass` in irb.

E: Yep, here it is: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F

Comment: I've seen `blank?` erroneously used in non-rails contexts before.  If you **really** need it you can [include it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4239625/645491): `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'`

Comment: When talking about `present?` don't forget to mention `presence`. http://blog.bmonkeys.net/2014/overview-about-nil-blank-present-presence-try-and-other-basic-things

Comment: As an addition to the all-blank-array gotcha that Tom is mentioning in his answer, be aware that this can lead to security issues where an attacker can use unprepared code that simply checks for unless params.nil? or unless params.blank?, and is the cause of much discussion and work currently in Rails. See here for more information: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13420

Comment: I am using something like this to avoid crashes on nil objects
if (myString.to_s.strip.length != 0)
    # do something
end

Comment: I've used `x.to_s.empty?`  on a number of occasions where I want to do the same thing whether a variable is nil or a string / array that is empty. `nil.to_s == ""`

Comment: `[ nil, '' ].all? &:blank? == true` returns `TypeError (wrong argument type FalseClass (expected Proc))` for ruby ruby 2.5.0p0

Answer (score 713):

I made this useful table with all the cases:

[image]

`blank?`, `present?` are provided by Rails.

Comment: It should be noted that blank? and present? are Rails-only. They return Exception: NoMethodError in Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: Consider adding `any?` if you ever update the table.

Comment: `blank?` and `present?` are not "_Rails-only_", they're automatically included by Rails but can easily be included in non-Rails code by using ActiveSupport's Core extensions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238867/how-do-i-use-active-support-core-extensions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 230):

Just extend Julian's table:

[image]

Ref: [empty?blank?nil?傻傻分不清楚](http://sibevin.github.io/posts/2014-11-11-103928-rails-empty-vs-blank-vs-nil)

Comment: @Sibevin Wang, I have downloaded this table and used it in some of my answers adding the credits to you. Hope you won't mind :) Kudos to this great effort!

Comment: `Enumerable#any?` is vanilla Ruby, it shouldn't be listed under "rails only"

Comment: @daniero Thanks for your reminder, the table is updated.

Comment: Numeric types also have `.zero?` and `.nonzero?`

Answer (score 66):

Quick tip: `!obj.blank? == obj.present?`

Can be handy/easier on the eyes in some expressions

Comment: is there something equivalent to !obj.nil?

Comment: `present?` is part of active_support, check here on what to include to get it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4648704/1569

Comment: @Kirk: !!obj is equivalent to !obj.nil?

Comment: @MohamedHafez No it's not. `!!false`

Comment: Agh, @Ajedi32 good catch! equivalent with that one exception.

Comment: To built on this answer...Corollary: `if obj.present?` and `unless obj.blank?` are the same. Hint: An excellent _guard clause_ is `return unless obj.present?`.

Answer (score 59):

[image]

- Everything that is `nil?` is `blank?`
- Everything that is `empty?` is `blank?`
- Nothing that is `empty?` is `nil?`
- Nothing that is `nil?` is `empty?`

tl;dr -- only use `blank?` & `present?` unless you want to distinguish between `""` and `"  "`

Answer (score 57):

One difference is that `.nil?` and `.empty?` are methods that are provided by the programming language Ruby, whereas `.blank?` is something [added](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/160638#706469) by the web development framework Rails.

Answer (score 18):

A special case is when trying to assess if a boolean value is nil:

```
false.present? == false
false.blank? == true
false.nil? == false
```

In this case the recommendation would be to use `.nil?`

Answer (score 16):

Just a little note about the `any?` recommendation: He's right that it's *generally* equivalent to `!empty?`. However, `any?` will return `true` to a string of just whitespace (ala `" "`).

And of course, see the 1.9 comment above, too.

Comment: In Rails, any string containing just whitespace characters is "blank":

    " \n\r\t".blank?  #=> true

Answer (score 15):

Don't forget `any?` which is generally `!empty?`. In Rails I typically check for the presence of something at the end of a statement with `if something` or `unless something` then use `blank?` where needed since it seems to work everywhere.

Comment: .any? doesn't work with strings in ruby 1.9, as .any? requires enumerable, and string#each by itself doesn't work in ruby 1.9.

Comment: Careful about `any?` for checking non-emptiness. It returns false if you have an array of falsy values. A way to get around that is to pass a always-true block: `[nil, false].any?{ true }`, but `!empty?` is shorter and you don't have remember the weird behavior.

Answer (score 14):

`nil?` is a standard Ruby method that can be called on all objects and returns `true` if the object is `nil`:

```
b = nil
b.nil? # => true
```

`empty?` is a standard Ruby method that can be called on some objects such as Strings, Arrays and Hashes and returns `true` if these objects contain no element:

```
a = []
a.empty? # => true

b = ["2","4"]
b.empty? # => false
```

`empty?` cannot be called on `nil` objects.

`blank?` is a Rails method that can be called on `nil` objects as well as empty objects.

Answer (score 9):

Everybody else has explained well what is the difference.

I would like to add in Ruby On Rails, it is better to use `obj.blank?` or `obj.present?` instead of `obj.nil?` or `obj.empty?`.

`obj.blank?` handles all types `nil`, `''`, `[]`, `{}`,  and returns `true` if values are not available and returns `false` if values are  available on any type of object.

Answer (score 8):

Though there n-number of answers available to this question but I liked the way its being explained here so posted one more answer :-)

**Look at the data metric below** - Its self explanatory with the various data-types used across available methods for it.

|  | #nil? | #empty? | #blank? | #present? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | false | NoMethodError | false | true |
| "" | false | true | true | false |
| " " | false | false | true | false |
| "\t\n" | false | false | true | false |
| [] | false | true | true | false |
| ["a"] | false | false | false | true |
| {} | false | true | true | false |
| {a: "b"} | false | false | false | true |
| Set.new | false | true | true | false |
| nil | true | NoMethodError | true | false |
| true | false | NoMethodError | false | true |
| false | false | NoMethodError | true | false |

Reference: https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/09/11/differences-between-nil-empty-blank-and-present.html

Answer (score 7):

`exists?` method can be used to check whether the data exists in the database or not. It returns boolean values either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Works only on model class!

Answer (score 6):

Rails 4

an alternative to @corban-brook 's *'Array gotcha: blank?'* for checking if an arrays only holds empty values and can be regarded as blank? true:

```
[ nil, '' ].all? &:blank? == true
```

one could also do:

```
[nil, '', "", " ",' '].reject(&:blank?).blank? == true
```

Answer (score 5):

`nil?` can be used on any object. It determines if the object has any value or not, including 'blank' values.

For example:

```
example = nil
example.nil?  # true

"".nil?  # false
```

Basically `nil?` will only ever return true if the object is in fact equal to 'nil'.

`empty?` is only called on objects that are considered a collection. This includes things like strings (a collection of characters), hashes (a collection of key/value pairs) and arrays (a collection of arbitrary objects). `empty?` returns true is there are no items in the collection.

For example:

```
"".empty? # true
"hi".empty?   # false
{}.empty?  # true
{"" => ""}.empty?   # false
[].empty?   # true
[nil].empty?  # false

nil.empty?  # NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

Notice that `empty?` can't be called on nil objects as nil objects are not a collection and it will raise an exception.

Also notice that even if the items in a collection are blank, it does not mean a collection is empty.

`blank?` is basically a combination of `nil?` and `empty?` It's useful for checking objects that you assume are collections, but could also be nil.