# How do I handle nils in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models set up:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :mode

  validates_presence_of :call, :mode
  validates_associated :mode, :band
  validates_presence_of :band, :if => :no_freq?
  validates_presence_of :freq, :if => :no_band?

protected

  def no_freq?
    freq.nil?
  end

  def no_band?
    band.nil?
  end
end

class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logs
end

class Mode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logs
end
```

When I enter a frequency on my *new* view it allows for no band to be specified if a freq is entered. This creates a problem in my other views though because band is now nil.  How do I allow for band not to be specified and just show up as empty on my *index* and *show* views, and then in the *edit* view allow one to be specified at a later point in time.

I have been able to get my *index* to display a blank by doing:

```
contact.band && contact.band.name
```

But I'm not sure if this is a best approach, and I'm unsure of how to apply a similar solution to my other views.

Many thanks from a rails newb!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my views, I use the following for potentially nil objects in my views:

```
<%= @contact.band.name unless @contact.band.blank? %>
```

if your object is an array or hash, you can use the empty? function instead.

```
<%= unless @contacts.empty? %>
 ..some code
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

D

Comment: Using unless with the .blank? method was just what I needed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can also do `<%= @contact.band.name if @contact.band.present? %>`

Comment: Your welcome badweather! Welcome to Stack Overflow btw and don't forget to accept the answer. (Shameless reputation grubbing) ;) And John is right, you can use an if method with "present?" Cheers!

Comment: Answer accepted. :)  Thanks John for that other suggestion as well. I will try both.

Answer (score 3):

A couple years old but still a top Google result for "rails view handle nil" so I'll add my suggestion for use with Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3p0.

In **application_helper.rb**, add this:

```
def blank_to_nbsp(value)
  value.blank? ? "&nbsp;".html_safe : value
end
```

Then to display a value in a view, write something like this:

```
<%= blank_to_nbsp contact.band %>
```

Benefits:

- "blank" catches both nil values and empty strings ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)).
- Simply omitting a nil object, or using an empty string, may cause formatting issues. `&nbsp;` pushes a non-breaking space into the web page and preserves formatting.
- With the "if" and "unless" suggestions in other answers, you have to type each object name twice. By using a helper, you only have to type each object name once.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= @contact.try(:band).try(:name) %>
```

This will return `nil` if `band` or `name` do not exist as methods on their respective objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Object#andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) for this:

```
<%= @contact.band.andand.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= @contact.band if @contact.band %>` also works