# render based on a condition, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form displaying a nested relationship. The call to render the nested child objects is made like below:

```
<% if @fpimgblocks %>
　　<% f.fields_for @fpimgblocks do |builder| %>
　　　　<%= render 'fpimgblock_fields', :f => builder %>
　　<% end %>
<% end %>
```

@fpimgblocks is the result of a find, I have verified there are zero results so I expect this to not render. However, the partial is rendered even through the object is not initialized. This then returns a nil_class error when I commit the form.

Is the syntax in the if statement wrong or something? I've tried changing to "unless @fpimgblocks.nil? but no change.

Comment: Have you tried,   <% unless @fpimgblocks.blank? %> 

This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@fpimgblocks` is not nil as you're expecting. Since it's the result of a find, it's actually an empty array.  Change this:

```
<% if @fpimgblocks %>
```

to this:

```
<% unless @fpimgblocks.empty? %>
```

And it will work.  I hope this helps!

Comment: .blank? is probably better in this case, as it handles the case @fpimgblocks is nil.  Otherwise @fpimgblocks.empty? will cause a NoMethodError.

Comment: You're right, it would - although I like `empty?` because it's more specific, and there's never a case where you would get a nil when you're calling `Object.all` or `Object.find(:all)`, which is the case in this example.