# In rails is there some object has nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there some object has nil? method, I want to know is there some method with nil?

Comment: are you asking "How do I test an object to see if it is Nil?"

Comment: I guess he's asking for `nil!` method...Note for `!`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar answered post here: [a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails/888877#888877)

Summarizing:

If you are using rails (not just ruby) there are three methods in your toolkit: **.nil?**, **.empty?** and **.blank?**

Follow the link to see the good description

Answer (score 0):

```
w.nil?
```

inverse of

```
!w.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `present?`, which acts as a sort of `!blank?`

Answer (score 0):

you could use `defined?` as well

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
1.9.3p125 :002 > Object.methods.grep(/nil/)
 => [:nil?]
```