# How to use present? in Ruby projects?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a script that uses Rails' extensions to the Ruby core Object class, and now I want to spin it off on its own. Rather than rewriting these, is there any library or extension that I can use to make them available independently?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't have to run Rails to use

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

or if you just want a specific extension, like `blank?` for string then just

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
```

I [looked up](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present%3F) `present?` and it's actually defined as

```
def present?
  !blank?
end
```

blank defined in active support as

```
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```

Comment: As tokland says below you can be even more specific: require "active_support/core_ext/object/blank"

Comment: Well, it is defined as !blank? but also requires that the blank method be added to just about every other class (also in that same file), so it's not quite that simple

Answer (score 9):

You can require specific functionality from [ActiveSupport](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html). In this case:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
[].present? #=> false
```