# Difference between .nil?, .blank? and .empty?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Can anyone tell me the difference between `nil?`, `blank?` and `empty?` in Ruby?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In Ruby, `nil` in an object (a single instance of the class `NilClass`). This means that methods can be called on it. `nil?` is a standard method in Ruby that can be called on *all* objects and returns `true` for the `nil` object and `false` for anything else.

`empty?` is a standard Ruby method on *some* objects like Arrays, Hashes and Strings. Its exact behaviour will depend on the specific object, but typically it returns `true` if the object contains no elements.

`blank?` is not a standard Ruby method but is added to *all* objects by Rails and returns `true` for `nil`, `false`, empty, or a whitespace string.

Because `empty?` is not defined for all objects you would get a `NoMethodError` if you called `empty?` on `nil` so to avoid having to write things like `if x.nil? || x.empty?` Rails adds the `blank?` method.

---

After answering, I found an earlier question, "[How to understand nil vs. empty vs. blank in Rails (and Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)", so you should check the answers to that too.

Comment: I have mistakenly downvote your answer, please edit some context so that I can revert back my downgrade vote!

Comment: @VKSingh I've made a minor edit to the answer if you'd still like to revert your vote. Thank you!

Answer (score 29):

Feel it ;)

NIL?

```
nil.nil?
#=> true
[].nil?
#=> false
"".nil?
#=> false
" ".nil?
#=> false
```

EMPTY?

```
[].empty?
#=> true
nil.empty?
#=> undefined method
"".empty?
#=> true
" ".empty?
#=> false
```

BLANK?

```
[].blank?
#=> true
nil.blank?
#=> true
"".blank?
#=> true
" ".blank?
#=> true
```

Answer (score 11):

Any Ruby variable is an object, so it can be uninitialized/unset (set to nil). `nil?` method returns true if it is not initialized:

```
b = nil
b.nil? # true
b = 'string value'
b.nil? # false
```

Arrays, strings, streams in Ruby can contain no data, so they can be empty. The `empty?` method returns true if so:

```
array = []
array.empty? # true
array << 5 << 4 # [5, 4]
array.empty? # false

string = "" # empty line
string.empty? # true
```

`blank?` is Active Support specific method (available in any object) and is available in Ruby On Rails with Active Support. It returns true if an object is nil or empty.

Comment: `blank?` if ActiveSupport method

Comment: @fl00r yes, you're right. i'll edit the answer