# allow_nil: false does not work from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Newbie here, trying to add some rules to a ruby on rails form, specifically I don't want to allow the creation of an item if this has not a name

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
belongs_to :project
validates :name, presence: true, allow_nil: false
end
```

Works smoothly if I create a new item from my app, but not happens the same if I create one item from rails console. How can I avoid the creation of an item without name, no matter if this has been created in the app or in the rails console?

Comment: How are you creating from the console? Show us the code.

Comment: wrwer = Idea.new > Idea.save

Comment: Still allows me to create new Idea without name.

Comment: I am lost, why do you need to set allow_nil or allow_blank? It is presence validator, it doesn't allow blank values by default.

Comment: Have you run `reload!` in your console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have to set `allow_blank: false` instead of `allow_nil: false`.

In Ruby an **`empty string`** is **`not nil`**.

```
"".nil?
#=> false

"".blank?
#=> true
```

Update your model like this

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  belongs_to :project
  validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false
end
```

If you want know the differences between `nil` and `blank`,see this **[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029256/difference-between-nil-blank-and-empty)** post.

Refer these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank)** for `allow_blank`

Comment: I highly recommend using `allow_blank` instead of `allow_nil` like this answer states. But also consider using the `nilify_blanks` gem to make sure you store `NULL`s instead of empty strings in the DB for empty values.

Answer (score -1):

Try this  from console:-

```
Idea.create(:name => "Something")
```

Rails console output:-

```
1.9.3-p385 :005 > c  = CabinNumber.create(:name => "Something")
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "cabin_numbers" ("created_at", "name", "status", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 25 May 2014 00:02:04 IST +05:30], ["name", "Something"], ["status", false], ["updated_at", Sun, 25 May 2014 00:02:04 IST +05:30]]
(139.6ms)  commit transaction
=> #<CabinNumber id: 11, name: "Something", status: false, created_at: "2014-05-24 18:32:04", updated_at: "2014-05-24 18:32:04">
```

OR

```
idea = Idea.new(:name => "hello")
idea.save
```

Rails console output:-

```
1.9.3-p385 :007 > c  = CabinNumber.new(:name => "hello")
=> #<CabinNumber id: nil, name: "hello", status: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p385 :008 > c.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "cabin_numbers" ("created_at", "name", "status", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 25 May 2014 00:02:57 IST +05:30], ["name", "hello"], ["status", false], ["updated_at", Sun, 25 May 2014 00:02:57 IST +05:30]]
(155.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Cannot create if name field is not provided

```
1.9.3-p385 :003 > c  = CabinNumber.create()
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<CabinNumber id: nil, name: nil, status: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment: Still allows me to create new Idea without name. <br> #<Idea id: 21, name: "", description: nil, picture: nil, created_at: "2014-05-24 18:31:45", updated_at: "2014-05-24 18:31:45", project_id: nil>

Comment: Both of your solutions include a text string on the 'name' field, if I'm including allow_nil: false, rails console should not allow me to create new items without name.