# What is the difference between using .exists?, and .present? in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make sure I'm using them for the correct occasion and want to know of any subtleties.  They seem to function the same way, which is to check to see if a object field has been defined, when I use them via the console and there isn't a whole lot information online when I did a google search. Thanks!

Comment: Those are Rails methods, not ruby: [ActiveResource::Base#exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-exists-3F), [Object#present?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)

Comment: if you want a pure ruby way, try `!!my_variable` (returns false if it's `nil` or `false`)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

To clarify: neither `present?` nor `exists?` are "pure" ruby—they're both from Rails-land.

### present?

`present?` is an ActiveSupport extension to `Object`. It's usually used as a test for an object's general "falsiness". From [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank):

> An object is `present` if it’s not `blank?`. An object is `blank` if it’s `false`, empty, or a whitespace string.

So, for example:

```
[ "", " ", false, nil, [], {} ].any?(&:present?)
# => false
```

### exists?

`exists?` is from ActiveResource. From [its documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/exists%3F/class):

> Asserts the existence of a resource, returning true if the resource is found.

```
Note.create(:title => 'Hello, world.', :body => 'Nothing more for now...')
Note.exists?(1) # => true
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: `exists?` is in ActiveRecord as well, not just ActiveResource.

Comment: `.present?` can avoid database query as well

Comment: Here someone has explained it nicely: https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/09/11/differences-between-nil-empty-blank-and-present.html

Answer (score 30):

The big difference between the two methods, is that when you call `present?` it initializes ActiveRecord for each record found(!), while `exists?` does not

to show this I added after_initialize on User. it prints: 'You have initialized an object!'

> User.where(name: 'mike').present?

```
User Load (8.1ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = $1 ORDER BY users.id ASC  [["name", 'mike']]
You have initialized an object!
You have initialized an object!
```

> User.exists?(name: 'mike')

```
User Exists (2.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = $1 ORDER BY users.id ASC LIMIT 1  [["name", 'mike']]
```

Answer (score 28):

There is a huge difference in performance, and `.present?` can be up to 10x slower then `.exists?` depending on the relation you are checking.

[This article](http://www.ombulabs.com/blog/benchmark/performance/rails/present-vs-any-vs-exists.html) benchmarks `.present?` vs `.any?` vs `.exists?` and explains why they go from slower to faster, in this order.

In a nutshell, `.present?` (**900ms in the example**) will load all records returned, `.any?` (**100ms in the example**) will use a SQLCount to see if it's > 0 and `.exists?` (**1ms in the example**) is the smart kid that uses SQL LIMIT 1 to just check if there's at least one record, without loading them all neither counting them all.

Comment: Worth noting that in rails 5.1 and up the perf difference between `any?` and `exists?` has been fixed and will be somewhat similar as explained in that article.

Comment: @dft do you have a link to this getting fixed in Rails 5.1?

Answer (score 9):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` would scan the records to get a count.

`SELECT 1` would stop after the first match, so their exec time would be very different.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL generated by the two are also different.

`present?`:

```
Thing.where(name: "Bob").present?
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM things WHERE things.name = "Bob";
```

`exists?`:

```
Thing.exists?(name: "Bob")
# => SELECT 1 AS one from things WHERE name ="Bob" limit 1;
```

They both seem to run the same speed, but may vary given your situation.

Answer (score -5):

You can avoid database query by using `present?`:

```
all_endorsements_11 = ArtworkEndorsement.where(user_id: 11)
ArtworkEndorsement Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "artwork_endorsements".* FROM "artwork_endorsements" WHERE "artwork_endorsements"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 11]]
all_endorsements_11.present?
=> true 
all_endorsements_11.exists?
ArtworkEndorsement Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "artwork_endorsements" WHERE "artwork_endorsements"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 11]]
=> true
```