# Performance differences between .exists? and .where.present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, rails-activerecord

What performance differences, if any, exist between the following two options ([mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26541498/38765))

```
Thing.where(name: "Bob").present?
```

which produces the SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM things WHERE things.name = "Bob";
```

and

```
Thing.exists?(name: "Bob")
```

which produces the SQL

```
SELECT 1 AS one from things WHERE name ="Bob" limit 1;
```

As the SQL statements are different, it's theoretically possible for differences in performance to exist. But I don't know whether, assuming `name` is indexed in the database, there's any practical difference. Also, is there any difference with regards to the amount of work being done in Ruby-land (such as initialization and GC).

If it makes any difference, I'm using Rails 3.2.20.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the benchmark by yourself like this:

```
$ bin/rails c
> ids = Item::Project.pluck(:id)
> b = Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
>   x.report("present?") { 10000.times { Item::Project.where(id: ids.sample).present? } }
>   x.report("exist?") { 10000.times { Item::Project.exists?(id: ids.sample) } }
> end
> puts b
  4.650000   0.270000   4.920000 (  7.627897)
  4.660000   0.330000   4.990000 (  7.337031)
```

**id** is indexed by database. If I choose a column which is not indexed, the result look like this:

```
  12.590000   0.740000  13.330000 ( 71.199677)
   8.350000   0.620000   8.970000 ( 34.846301)
```

There are about 30000 records for this table. So **present?** is slower than **exist?** because it has to count all matched records first.