# Rails Image Conditional Won't Work in Heroku Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, carrierwave, image-uploading

I had to reconfigure my uploader.  I'm using `carrierwave` and `minimagick`.  So in a nutshell, I had images automatically processed/resized when they were initially uploaded before.  Now I don't want them automatically processed, I'm keeping the original size and creating a version named `normal` for the resized image.

Now some images that are uploaded will have the `normal` version.  But images that were uploaded prior to the reconfiguration won't.  To avoid broken images, I've created a conditional that works great in development.

```
  <% if car.picture_attachments.first.picture.normal.present? %>
        <%= image_tag(car.picture_attachments.first.picture.normal.url) %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag(car.picture_attachments.first.picture) %>
      <% end %>
```

But in Heroku - it thinks every object has a `normal` version and is serving a bunch of broken images as a result.  I'm using Amazon S3 - any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use this:

`<% if car.picture_attachments.first.picture.normal.file.exists? %>`

difference between `present?` and `exists?` is important.  See difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186788/5551783

Note `exists?` is far slower than `present?` because it checks the database for each instance.