# Rails, is find_by().present? more performant than where().exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, activerecord, query-optimization

This question arose from me doing 2 types of performance tweaks:

- changing a lot of my `where().present?` statements to `where().exists?`
- changing a lot of my `where().first` to `find_by()`

Sitting at the intersection of this is situations where I had previously written `.where().first.present?` and I'm wondering what would be more performant to change it to: `.find_by().present?` or `.where().exists?`

Answer (score 3):

- Changing `where().present?` to `where().exists?`

`where().present?` or `find_by().present?` will always fetch the complete user record from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE xyz.name = 'Deepesh'
```

whereas `where().exists?` or `where().any?` will run this query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM xyz WHERE xyz.name = 'Deepesh' LIMIT 1
```

So obviously `exists?` or `any?` would be better in terms of performance until you need that record you are checking to fetch some information or use it somewhere, for example:

```
user = User.find_by(name: 'Deepesh')
user.do_something if user.present?
```

so here you need to perform some action on that user if the record is present then using `present?` would be sensible.

**Note:** The time we would save using `exists?` would be the initialization of the `ActiveRecord` object, `present?` would initialize one, and `exists` will not. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30192978/4207394

Comment: To clarify: so you're saying if you DO need to use the record found, use `.find_by().present?`; if you do NOT need to use the record found, use '.where().exists?`, correct?

Comment: Yes, because if you need to use that record below in the code then you will have to run two queries with `exists?`, one which will check if the record exists or not and one which would fetch the row from DB. So if you need to use the record below just fetch the record and check if it is present or not