# How do I test a has_many :through association that also has a validates_presence_of validation on the association with Factory Girl in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, testing, factory-bot

I'm trying to test a model with Factory Girl that has a validates_presence_of on a has_many :through association with. Although the form is working fine and I can write a test that fills out the form manually, I'm not able to get a valid factory. This test keeps failing:

```
it "has a valid work factory" do
    work = FactoryGirl.build(:work)
    work.should be_valid
end
```

Here's the error message:

```
Work has a valid work factory
     Failure/Error: work.should be_valid
       expected #<Work id: nil, name: "Client Website", date: "2013-06-03 16:13:08", client: #<Client id: 1, name: "Client Number 4", client_code: "CN4", created_at: "2013-06-04 16:13:12", updated_at: "2013-06-04 16:13:12">, description: "A great new website for the client.", image: "/image.jpg", service: "Web", featured: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Client can't be blank
```

Here's my factories.rb file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email)        { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password                "secret"
    password_confirmation   "secret"

    factory :admin do
      after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:admin)}
    end
  end

  factory :client do
    sequence(:name)          { |n| "Client Number #{n}"}
    sequence(:client_code)   { |n| "CN#{n}"}
  end

  factory :work do
    name            "Client Website"
    client
    date            1.day.ago
    description     "A great new website for the client."
    image           "/image.jpg"
    service         "Web"
    featured        true
  end  
end
```

My work model:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client, :client_ids, :date, :description, :featured, :image, :name, :service

  validates_presence_of :client_ids
  validates_presence_of :date, :image, :name
  validates_length_of   :description, :in => 5..500, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :name, :in => 5..50

  has_many :postings
  has_many :clients, :through => :postings  
end
```

My client model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_code, :name

  validates_presence_of     :client_code, :name
  validates_uniqueness_of   :name
  validates_length_of       :client_code, :is => 3
  validates_length_of       :name, :in => 5..50

  has_many  :postings
  has_many  :works, :through => :postings  
end
```

It seems like this test should pass because the factory is getting built with a client. But I'm not sure why that validation is causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `expected ..... to be valid, but got errors: Client can't be blank`

```
work = FactoryGirl.build(:work) # this returns an unsaved object
```

By using `build` you haven't saved the object. The object is `nil`. If an object is [`nil` it is `blank`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

You want to save the object on creation like this

```
work = FactoryGirl.create(:work) # this returns a saved object
```

Now

```
work.should be_valid
```

should pass

UPDATE:

I didn't look closely enough at your `factories.rb'

```
factory :work do
  name            "Client Website"
  client
  date            1.day.ago
  description     "A great new website for the client."
  image           "/image.jpg"
  service         "Web"
  featured        true
end
```

your `client` attribute in the `work` factory is literally blank. This wont pass validation and wont save the object. Fill in `client` in the factory or pass in something on creation like this

```
work = FactoryGirl.create(:work, client: "fill in with client")
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm getting the same error on create   3) `Work has a valid work factory
     Failure/Error: work = FactoryGirl.create(:work)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Client can't be blank
     # ./spec/integration/factories_spec.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: I can create a new work through the browser just fine. FactoryGirl.build(:work) also returns a work object that includes an associated client that's generated by Factory Girl, and that looks ok too.