# Is !object.nil? == object.present? in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it safe to assume that `!object.nil? == object.present?` in Rails, or are there gotchas? Here's a scenario:

```
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil? # Would current_user.present? mean the same thing here?
  end

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies[:token] = user.token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(token: cookies[:token]) if cookies[:token]
  end
```

Comment: !object.blank? == object.present?, and it's also interesting to check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.present?` is the negation of `.blank?`, which is similar but decidedly unique from `.nil?`.

`.nil?` only evaluates whether an object is `NilClass`.

`.blank?` evaluates to `true` when evaluating a string that is not empty and may (or may not) contain whitespace.

It's superfluous to your question, but it's probably handy to note that `.blank?` and `.present?` are Rails methods, whereas `.nil?` is pure Ruby.

EDIT:

If, in your example, `object` is equal to `false`, then **no, it's not safe to assume that `!object.nil? == object.present?`**. However, if `object` is actually a Ruby/Rails object, then it's safe to assume that the statement will evaluate to true.

```
!false.nil? == false.present? #=> false
```

Comment: I understand, thanks. I still can't figure out if it makes a difference in my use case, though...

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. Don't worry about it.

Comment: "`blank?` evaluates to `true` when evaluating a string that is not empty and ..." - is this accurate? In my rails console, evaluating `''.blank?` returns `true`. So does `nil.blank?`.

Answer (score 3):

In rails generally I dont think so according to the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F).

But the following should be true

```
!object.blank? == object.present?
```

In your case I think it should be true because of how the method `current_user` is defined.

Comment: `"".nil? # => false` | `"".present? # => false` |  `"".blank # => true` |

Comment: See also the documentation for [`Object#blank?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F) - An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, “”, “ ”, nil, [], and {} are all blank

Comment: I understand now, but I'm not sure if there's a subtle issue with my use case... i.e. if I changed from `!nil?` to `present?` -- as far as I can see it's a negative.