# Handling a nil value from an instance method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Product` model which has many `Items`. The application lists unique items which belong to a product. So think of items as inventory. The following query grabs featured items for a product and removes the first item (irrelevant, but it becomes a featured item, displayed separately, if you're curious).

```
# product.rb
has_many :items_in_stock, -> { Item.in_stock }, class_name: 'Item'
def featured_items
  items_in_stock.select("DISTINCT ON (condition) id, items.*")
    .order(:condition, :price)
    .sort_by { |item| item[:price] }[1..-1]
end

# item.rb
scope :in_stock, -> { where(status: 'in_stock') }
```

The trouble is when the `feaured_items` are empty, the method returns nil, and not a relation object. This means I get an error if I call `@product.featured_items.any?` on a product that has no items. If I remove the `sort_by` block, I get an empty relation object.

Is there a good way to handle this other than:

```
items = items_in_stock.select("DISTINCT ON (condition) id, items.*").order(:condition, :price)
if items.any?
  items.sort_by { |item| item[:price] }[1..-1]
end
```

I can't reverse the ordering of the query because I get an error saying the order of the conditions in the order by statement must match the group conditions.

Comment: _"The trouble is when the `feaured_items` are empty"_ I don't see `featured_items` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Phrogz sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `if items.any?` you can use `unless items.blank?` if it's nil or empty, it won't run the condition

`items.blank?` checks both `items.empty?` and `items.nil?`

And of course you can use it in your featured_items

```
items = items_in_stock.select("DISTINCT ON (condition) id, items.*")
  .order(:condition, :price)
  .sort_by { |item| item[:price] }[1..-1]
return Array.new if items.blank?
```

That way you know that result will be an array, no matter what

And for [the proof](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/888877/1434075), you can use `.blank?` on a `nil` object, and it works on `nil` itself, `nil.blank?` returns `true`

Comment: You can actually do `nil.blank?` and it will return `true`. Just go test it. And for the proof: http://stackoverflow.com/a/888877/1434075

Comment: Can you just make an edit to your post, that way I can: `You last voted on this answer
19 hours ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited`

Comment: Sweet up-voted :). Sorry for that I was looking at Ruby, not Rails.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused...why call `.any?` on it then since `nil` is treated as `false` in ruby. If what you get back is `nil` then you know that you don't have any featured_items.

I ran this in `irb` and I think your issue is the [1..-1].

```
a = []
# => []
a.sort_by { |w| w.length }
# => []
a.sort_by { |w| w.length }[1..-1]
# => nil
```

The easiest way is to just do

```
items = items_in_stock.select("DISTINCT ON (condition) id, items.*")
  .order(:condition, :price)
  .sort_by { |item| item[:price] }
items.any? ? items[1..-1] : items
```

Then you don't actually have to do a check in other parts of your code unless it's necessary.

Comment: I suppose that's true, but for the sake of consistency. Usually, ActiveRecord returns a relation object. Calling `any?` tells you if the array has any elements.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on plucking the first value from the array, but returning an array, even if its empty?

Comment: By the way, on other occasions I might call `.size` or anything else on it, so it will fail anyway, unless it's not empty. So `any?` is not the only issue. Like I said, it's a question of consistency.

Comment: I guess that's pretty much to be expected. It feels hackish, though. I might have to revise how to treat the "featured item" and "featured items" as they get separate handling in the view.

Comment: Yea it does feel hackish. You might want to create some instance methods to handle this all for you, and leave the lookup as a method for itself.