# if statement to hide notification when nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement

I have this code:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <a href="#" class="alert-link"><%= notice %></a>
</div>
```

I need to put an if statement around it to only show the entire div if `notice` isn't nil. I've tried a couple of ways but can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use [`nil?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F) method of the `Object` class of ruby

```
<% unless notice.nil? %>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link"><%= notice %></a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Above code show the entire div if notice isn't nil.

I'll also recommend you to [read difference between `nil`, `blank?` & `present`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Replacing first line with `<% if notice.present? %>` would also check for `false` or "blank" objecte, e.g. empty strings.

Comment: @MarekLipka present? also return false false for `''`, `' '`, `nil`, `false` amd question says `I need to put an if statement around it to only show the entire div if notice isn't nil`

Comment: `false` for `nil` isn't "false". And that's why I put it on comment instead of separate answer, as some kind of suggestion to question Author.

Comment: `1.9.3-p327 :024 > false.nil?
 => false `

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean `nil.present? # => false` and that's correct `false`, not "false" `false` like you wrote in comment.

Comment: Yeah i got it @MarekLipka what you want to say, even i used `blank?`, `present?` methods only instead of `nil?`. But, as she want to hide div only when `notice` is `nil` i write `unless notice.nil?` instead of `if nil.present?`

Comment: You are right, of course, usage of `nil` meets perfectly question criteria as they are expressed.

Answer (score 2):

All given ansers are correct, altough I prefer this one using rails presence check:

```
<% if notice.present? %>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <a href="#" class="alert-link"><%= notice %></a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It is a detail, but is more robust since this condition will correctly evaluate to false when using empty string (or empty array, if you might be using multiple notices in the future).

And it reads flawlessly, doesn't it :)

Comment: present? also return false false for `''`, `'  '`, `nil`, `false`

Comment: Yeah that's ok, I've just mistakenly used the unless instead of if. Thanks for noticing, I've made the correction!