# Should I use `.blank?` in a view of performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, memory, ruby-on-rails-4

I understand what `.blank?` , `.nil?` and `.empty?` does now.

I'm thinking why should I not replace all the `.nil?` and `.empty?` to `.blank?` for less risks of making mistakes. For example, `if current_user.blank?`

Is there a **performance issue** for `.blank?` method? Is it *slower* or *consuming more memory*?

If it is, how bad is it? As bad as string vs symbol?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its worrying you are that inconfident in your coding skills. I dont see any reason to always use .blank?

Comment: `.nil?` returns `true`  is instance is `nil`, `.empty?` returns `true` when instance, like array or string is empty. and `blank?` should return `true` if nil or empty.

Comment: `current_user.blank?` is a tad overkill, it doesn't make sense for a user to be empty.

Comment: Sorry for misleading title. It must be a very common fact that everyone answers from title in SO.

Comment: I mean not only title but and the context of the message. What is the performance in your meaning?

Comment: @IvanWang Sorry, for the harsh word... I've changed my post.

Comment: It's okay. I have got the answer any way. I was over-thinking how .blank? is processed in rails.

Comment: I've added some investigations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Theory

All three methods have various realizations for various classes:

1. `:nil?`:

   ```
   # NilClass
   def nil?
     true
   end

   # Object
   def nil?
     false
   end
   ```
2. `:empty?`:

   ```
   # String, Array
   def empty?
     if self.size == 0
       true
     else
       false
     end
   end
   ```
3. `:blank?`:

   ```
   # FalseClass, NilClass
   def blank?
     true
   end

   # Object
   def blank?
     respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
   end

   # TrueClass
   def blank?
     false
   end

   # String
   def blank?
     self !~ /[^[:space:]]/
   end
   ```

As you may see the various classes implement various methods style. In case of `String` class it takes time of a single `Regexp`, in case of `Object`, including `Hash`, and `Array` it takes time of call to `:respond` and return a value `nil` or not `Object`. The seconds are just operations that takes time similar to `:nil?`. `:respond?` method checks the presense of the `:empty?` method that takes theoretically slight more times than two times 
to `:empty?`.

### Investigations

I wrote simple script that simulates the behaviour of those methods, and calculates execution time of them:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark'

obj = Object.new
array = []
empty_string = ''
non_empty_string = '   '

funcs = 
[ proc { empty_string.empty? }, 
  proc { non_empty_string.empty? },
  proc { obj.nil? },
  proc { nil.nil? },
  proc { true },
  proc { respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self },
  proc { array.respond_to?(:empty?) ? array.empty? : !array },
  proc { non_empty_string !~ /[^[:space:]]/ } ]

def ctime func
   time = 0
   1000.times { time += Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { func.call } }.to_a[5].to_f }
   rtime = time /= 1000000
end

funcs.each {| func | p ctime( func ) }
```

And results:

```
# empty String :empty?
# 4.604020118713379e-07
# non_empty String :empty?
# 4.5903921127319333e-07
# Object :nil?
# 5.041143894195557e-07
# NilClass :nil?
# 4.7951340675354e-07
# FalseClass, NilClass, TrueClass :blank?
# 4.09862756729126e-07
# main :blank? ( respond_to returns false )
# 6.444177627563477e-07
# Array :blank? ( respond_to returns true )
# 6.491720676422119e-07
# String :blank?
# 1.4315705299377442e-06
```

As you may see, obvious champion from the end of table in case of speed is method `:blank?` of `String` class. It has execution time descreased in 3-4 times against an simple `empty?` method of a class. Object's `:blank?` method has only 1.5 times execution time degradation. Note, that `:respond_to` method in it has just a few time to execute, becase as far as I see the *ruby* interpreter caches the result of its execution. So, conclusion. Try to avoid using String's `.blank?` method.

Additional, if you need to know how to use the methods see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: This is a great full detail report of everything! Thank you so much. Learnt much more than I have expected. Right, `.blank?` is doing too perfect on checking white space string. But not so perfect on checking array. Really interesting.

Comment: @IvanWang  Vise versa, `:blank?` on `String` takes more time then the same on `Array` or `Hash`. so on `String` it becomes worse more than twice.

Comment: I have confused you again. I meant `.blank?` is doing literally perfect on string, because it checks every white space in string. You are right, doing too perfect surely will make it slow. However, `.blank?` decided to not do white space checking on array. That makes it seems "half-way-done". (I think that is for a good reason. If it does white space check on every instant inside an array, it will take ages if the array is full of white space instances.)

Comment: Yes, functionally `:blank?` for `String` is better, then `Array`'s one. May be it because of that `Array` `[nil]`, or `Hash` `{ nil => nil }` aren't frequently occurred in Rails =)

Answer (score 3):

check the source here [blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)

```
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
end
```

Technically its a 2x of `empty?`

*is there a performance issue for .blank? ? Is it slower or consuming more memory?*

Well, that depends on lot of factors

- amount of data your app handles
- server hardware
- no of incoming requests

But frankly this is not gonna bother you unless you run twitter

Comment: Nice. The source codes help me understand much better. 2X .empty? sounds reasonable. Now I can just feel free to use more .blank on small scale projects.