# undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a situation where i wish to show a link on if someone has never created an event (invite) or if the last invite was more than 30 days ago.

However, this code wont work;

```
<% if current_user.invites.nil? || ( current_user.invites && (Date.today - current_user.invites.last.created_at) >= 30.days) %> 

<% end %>
```

Someone help me re-organise this in a way that works especially the conditions after the OR option.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `current_user.invites` returns an array, you should not use `.nil?` because arrays with no items are not `nil`, are *empty*, so this `invites` array will be empty (`[]`) when has no items, so you can use [`#empty?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F).

Also I removed the second condition because there is no need to check if the `invites` is not empty. In other words, if the `invites` array is empty, the right side of the OR (`||`) condition is not going to be evaluated.

```
<% if current_user.invites.empty? || (Date.today - current_user.invites.last.created_at) >= 30.days %> 

<% end %>
```

I would also recommend you to extract this code in a [*custom helper method*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActionView/Custom_Helpers), so your code will be a little more DRY.

```
# app/helpers/my_helper.rb
module MyHelper
  def invites_created_after_or_none?(user = current_user, days = 30.days)
    user.invites.empty? || (Date.today - user.invites.last.created_at) >= days
  end
end

<% if invites_created_after_or_none? %> 

<% end %>
```

Comment: i suggest using `blank?` instead of `empty?` as it's more generic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: IMHO, for arrays sound much better `empty?` than `blank?` I also prefer using pure Ruby methods if possible and there is no gain, and `empty` is implemented in Rails.