# Check whether an attribute of a model exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In Rails, I am getting an error when I try to evaluate whether the user has entered a brand for their computer:

`if @user.computer.brand.empty?`

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'brand' for nil:NilClass):`

If the user has not entered a computer, this will return an error that there is no method `brand` on `nil class`. What is the correct way to check that a user has both entered a `computer` and a `brand` for that computer?

Comment: simplest solution would be to just use `if @user.computer && @user.computer.brand.empty?` but a cleaner solution would be to use Null objects as specified in this article http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `try`:

```
@user.computer.try(:brand)
```

This will return `nil` if either `computer` or `computer.brand` is `nil`, or it will return the assigned `brand`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if @user.computer && @user.computer.brand.present?
```

Comment: Add some explanation to answer please so other as well as user can understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
if @user.computer.present? && @user.computer.brand.present?
```

You can also use `! nil?` instead of present.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails) - very useful