# Rails object returns false on present? but true on !nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a database object in active record. If I call `object.find(1).present?` it returns `false`, but it exists. Calling `!object.find(1).nil?` returns `true`.

Why is this? I thought `!nil == present?`.

Comment: `present? == !blank?`

Comment: Just show us the code, you are playing with. Just do run those code in Rails console and copy and paste those relevant part of your code..

Answer (score 5):

`nil?` and `present?` are **not** opposites.

Many things are both  *not* `present?`  *and* not `nil?`, such as an empty string or empty array.

```
"".present? # => false
"".nil? # => false

[].present? # => false
[].nil? # => false
```

Answer (score 5):

To better answer your question lets look at the implementation:

```
def present?
  !blank?
end
```

We don't see `nil?` mentioned here, just `blank?`, so lets check out `blank?` as well:

```
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```

So essentially, if the object `responds_to` `empty?` it will call out to that for the result. Objects which have an `empty?` method include Array, Hash, String, and Set.

**Further Reading**

- [The Blank/Present Source in ActiceSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/126dc47665c65cd129967cbd8a5926dddd0aa514/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L22)
- [A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: It might be good to point out that in the case of String, `blank?` differs from `empty?` in that a string with all whitespace is blank but not empty.