# Rails scope join with another model scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a situation i need to join the 4 scopes among the 4 scopes 3 are written in model(A) and one in another model(B) how to join those scopes?

those two models have HABTM relationship

```
Model A
  scope 1
  scope 2
  scope 3

  total_scope= scope1.scope2.scope3.scope4
end

Model B
  scope 4
end
```

Comment: err, can you use a real example? this is completely confusing

Comment: possible duplicate of [A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 18):

Your question isn't very well worded, but I think what you're asking is related to [Active Record's merge feature](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge):

```
class ModelA
  scope :total_scope, -> { scope1.scope2.scope3.joins(:modelb).merge(ModelB.scope4)
end
```