# display the field even though it is empty for some objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display the school name for the users. When they sign up users can select a school which they belong to (not everyone does though so sometimes this column is left blank).

At the moment I have:

```
if user.is_a? Student
  %td= user.school
end
```

which finds the schools that the students belong to, but displays it as the activerecord record. Each of the schools has a name and if I select a single student and do: `@student.school.name` it gives me the name of the school with no issues.

However if I do:

```
if user.is_a? Student
  %td= user.school.name
end
```

It keeps throwing up `undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass`

I am pretty sure this is because some of the students don't have a school. I have tried to add this to the if statement but I can't seem to make it work. I tried variations of:

```
if user.is_a? Student && !user.school.blank?
```

with `.any?`, `.empty?` but none of them work, they just so `no method .blank?` etc.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do one of these things

A) quickest

```
 %td= user.school && user.school.name
```

B) cleanest (or, at least, cleaner)

```
#in user class
def school_name
  self.school && self.school.name
end

#in view
%td= user.school_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `try` (http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method here

```
if user.is_a? Student
  %td= user.school.try(:name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one-liner with `present?` method for showing one value when no school present and school name when it is present:

```
%td= user.school.present? ? user.school.name : '-'
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663389/1677069) is a nice table that explains differences between methods like `nil?`, `empty?`, `present?` etc.

**NB!** It's not good practice to write logic into view-files so I suggest putting it inside helper method:

inside **view:**

```
%td= school_name(user)
```

inside **user_helper.rb:**

```
def school_name(user)
  user.school.present? ? user.school.name : '-'
end
```