# undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass how to avoid it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi Together I've got this code:

```
 @coursesFound = @user.available_courses
@courses = []

for course in @coursesFound do
  @courseInGroups = course.user_groups
  for group in @courseInGroups do
    @group = UserGroup.find group.id
    if @group.users.map { |u| u.id }.include? @user.id
      @courses << course
      break
    end
  end
end

# Wenn ein Kurs keiner Gruppe hinzugefügt wurde
if @courseInGroups.empty?
  @courses << course
end
```

on my debian vm it works fine but on my live system I got this error:

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What is `@courseInGroups`?

Comment: added more code above

Comment: in CoursesFound is an object with lots of courses.

Comment: @Felix more = other, your code doesn't include the `empty?` call any more.

Comment: sorry added wrong code :) now its all in

Comment: apparently, `@courseInGroups` and therefore `course.user_groups` is `nil`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this `@coursesFound = @user.available_courses` returns an empty activerecord relation.

Then this won't execute

```
for course in @coursesFound do
  @courseInGroups = course.user_groups
  for group in @courseInGroups do
    @group = UserGroup.find group.id
    if @group.users.map { |u| u.id }.include? @user.id
      @courses << course
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Which means when you get here `@courseInGroups` is nil

```
if @courseInGroups.empty?
  @courses << course
end
```

So your quick fix would be

```
if @courseInGroups && @courseInGroups.empty?
  @courses << course
end
```

Comment: Or you could replace `empty?` with `blank?`

Comment: Yeah, that'd work.  Clearly I'm a bit slow this morning :)

Comment: problem solved .. I have to put the `if @courseInGroups.empty?
  @courses << course
end` in the first for

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method to Avoid this error:

```
@courseInGroups.try(:empty?)
```

This won't throw an error if `@courseInGroups` was nil.

Comment: what does it do? mask it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly initialize your object as well.

```
@courseInGroups = course.user_groups || []
```

You won't get `nil:NilClass` error any more if you initialize properly.

To get rid of `nil:NilClass` error you can use other answer. like `try` etc.

Comment: Just in case "course.user_groups" will return an ActiveRecord relation, which is different from "[]" which is an array. Using "**Course.none**" (_Model.none_) would return an **empty** ActiveRecord relation, and that would be better instead of "[]".

Answer (score 2):

And don't forget `blank?` when using rails. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails) you find a good overview of all methods with or without rails.

I did not analyze your code, it's just for you, me and others that do not use this methods often, mix them up and then come here - just to remember: `empty?` is not `blank?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `?` before the dot of the `empty`:

```
if @courseInGroups?.empty
```