# Why isn't this simple elsif working in Rails/Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

- If there is a flash notice > "Flash notice"
- If there isn't a flash notice and you're on the homepage > "Welcome"

Code:

```
<% if flash %>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :span, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
<% elsif current_page('/') %>
  <% print 'Hi' %>
<% end %>
```

It prints the flashes correctly but not the welcome on the home page. Doesn't seem to matter if I try `current_page` or `root_url` or `print 'Welcome'` or just plain `"Welcome"` with no code wrapper. Why?

Comment: The `elsif` check will only occur when `flash` is "falsey" - what is the value of `flash` when you're expecting the `eslif` check to happen?

Comment: I suspect that `flash` is merely an empty hash rather than false or nil (which are Ruby's only "falsy" values). That is,  `if {}` is actually `true`.

Comment: See [A concise explanation of nil vs blank vs empty in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, almost, I wasn't checking the flash properly at the beginning of the block. This works now:

```
<% if flash.present? %>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :span, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
<% elsif current_page?('/') %>
  Welcome to The Spain Report.
<% end %>
```

Thank you all!