# Rails unable to validate the presence of name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write a validation test for the name attribute in order to check if its present. My user_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

end
```

My user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates(:name, presence: true)
end
```

My I/O in the console when testing:

```
2.2.1 :007 > user = User.new(name: "", email: "ex@example.com")
 => #<User id: nil, name: "", email: "ex@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.1 :008 > user.valid?
 => true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting error, because it is not `nil`. Understand the difference between `nil` and `blank` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888877/1381240)

You need to provide validation like this to avoid having blank values:

```
validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `presence: true` validate if the attribute is not `nil`. You need to use `allow_blank` to validate if a string is empty or not.

```
validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false
```

Check out the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) about this topic.

Comment: `"   ".blank?` would results `true`. So `allow_blank: false` would be sufficient. You may try this in console.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'll keep this in mind as I move deeper into the validation process.

Comment: @Dusht: Actually true. Thanks for the hint :-)