# rake aborted! undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some rake tasks defined and within those tasks; there is a code as follows

```
task :stale => :environment do |_, args|
    if args.extras.empty?
```

When I run the task; it gets aborted with the following error

> rake aborted! undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
>   /lib/tasks/:387:in `block (3 levels) in '
>   /vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bugsnag-2.8.12/lib/bugsnag/rake.rb:12:in
>   `execute_with_bugsnag' Tasks: TOP =>

How could this error be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NilClass` simply does not have a method called `empty?` and `args.extras` is obviously nil at the moment.

The best alternative in this case is `blank?` which will return true if the array/string is empty or if `args.extra` is nil.

```
task :stale => :environment do |_, args|
    if args.extras.blank?
```

Here’s a nice table from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails) showing the differences between `empty?`, `blank?`, etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot idmean. This reply really helped a lot.