# What determines the return value of `present?`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some valid `ActiveRecord` objects return `false` for `present?`:

```
object.nil? # => false
object.valid? # => true
object.present? # => false
object.blank? # => true
```

I prefer `object.present?` over `not object.nil?`. What determines the return value of `present?`/`blank?`?

EDIT: Found the answer: I had redefined the `empty?` method on this class, not the `blank?` or `present?` method; along the lines of @Simone's answer, `blank?` is using `empty?` behind the scenes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I prefer `object.present?` over `not object.nil?`--If you want something non-standard, then just define it by yourself and use it. If you don't want to do that, then don't prefer like that.

Comment: *"Some valid `ActiveRecord` objects return `false` for `present?`"* - really? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 7):

`present?` is the opposite of `blank?`. `blank?` implementation depends on the type of object. Generally speaking, it returns true when the value is empty or like-empty.

You can get an idea [looking at the tests for the method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5.1/activesupport/test/core_ext/object/blank_test.rb):

```
  BLANK = [ EmptyTrue.new, nil, false, '', '   ', "  \n\t  \r ", '　', "\u00a0", [], {} ]
  NOT   = [ EmptyFalse.new, Object.new, true, 0, 1, 'a', [nil], { nil => 0 } ]

  def test_blank
    BLANK.each { |v| assert_equal true, v.blank?,  "#{v.inspect} should be blank" }
    NOT.each   { |v| assert_equal false, v.blank?, "#{v.inspect} should not be blank" }
  end

  def test_present
    BLANK.each { |v| assert_equal false, v.present?, "#{v.inspect} should not be present" }
    NOT.each   { |v| assert_equal true, v.present?,  "#{v.inspect} should be present" }
  end
```

An object can define its own interpretation of `blank?`. For example

```
class Foo
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
  def blank?
    @value != "foo"
  end
end

Foo.new("bar").blank?
# => true

Foo.new("foo").blank?
# => false
```

If not specified, it will fallback to the closest implementation (e.g. `Object`).

Comment: Why `EmptyTrue` and `EmptyFalse` instead of the singleton TrueClass/FalseClass?

Comment: @max take a look at the test, these are test classes with a custom implementation of `empty?`. And regarding `TrueClass`/`FalseClass` - try to create an instance via `TrueClass.new` (won't work).

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, why use a stand-in instead of `true` / `false`. It just seems weird to stub out the object under test.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`Object#present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)

> An object is present if it's not blank.

In your case, object is blank, so `present?` will return `false`. Validity of the object does not really matter.

Comment: So, the question is, why is my object blank? And I just figured it out: I redefined the `empty?` method and apparently it's using this.