# Rails method to detect array of empty strings (["", "",...]) as empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string

Is there a rails function to detect `["", "", ...]` (i.e. An array containing only empty string or strings) as empty

My requirement:

`[""].foo?` => true

`["", ""].foo?` => true

`["lorem"].foo?` => false

`["", "ipsum"].foo?` => false

I tried using `array.reject!(&:empty?).blank?`. It worked, but this changed my array. I don't want my array to be changed. Please help me find a compact method.

Comment: Look [Array gotcha:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/888877/2767755) part of this answer.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There isn't a single method, but you can use [`.all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).

```
["", nil].all?(&:blank?) # => true
["ipsum", ""].all?(&:blank?) # => false
```

Or you can get the opposite result with [`.any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

```
["", nil].any?(&:present?) # => false
["lorem", ""].any?(&:present?) # => true
```

Comment: I wonder if `.all?` would be more performant on large Arrays (if it returns immediately when it finds something other than the expected value)?

Answer (score 3):

OP was asking for a solution for Rails but I came here while looking for a generic Ruby solutions. Since `present?` and `blank?` are both Rails extensions the above solution did not work for me (unless I pull in ActiveSupport which I didn't want).

May I instead offer a simpler solution:

```
[nil, nil].join.empty? # => true
["", nil].join.empty? # => true
["lorem", nil].join.empty? # => false
```