# Have Hanami an alternative for .present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hanami

Rails has useful `present?` method. How can I check the same in [Hanami](http://hanamirb.org/)?

Comment: What is the use case for using `present?`. Is that for parameter checking? There are better ways of doing that than calling `present?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`present?` is the opposite of `blank?` in Ruby on Rails.

**You could use `Hanami::Utils::Blank`:**

```
require 'hanami/utils/blank'

Hanami::Utils::Blank.blank?(nil)     #=> true
Hanami::Utils::Blank.blank?(' ')     #=> true
Hanami::Utils::Blank.blank?('Artur') #=> false
```

However there are two concerns:

- `blank?` is not equal to `Hanami::Utils::Blank.blank?`
- `Hanami::Utils::Blank.blank?` [is considered to be part of a private API](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/hanami-utils/Hanami%2FUtils%2FBlank.blank%3F)

> This method is part of a private API. You should avoid using this method if possible, as it may be removed or be changed in the future.

**You could use `ActiveSupport` without Ruby on Rails**

[Active Support](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) is a collection of utility classes and standard library extensions. It's a separate gem and you can use it independently.

**You could extend `Object`:**

```
class Object
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
  end

  def present?
    !blank?
  end
end
```

**And the last option**

You may prefer using pure Ruby and its `nil?` and `empty?` methods if semantics is suitable.

Comment: And there are plenty of ways to do this cleanly in [pure Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26877095/3784008).