# Rails 5.2: Difference of if current_user vs current_user.present? in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I follow [this post](https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/benchmark/performance/rails/present-vs-any-vs-exists.html). In my view:

```
- if current_user
- if current_user.present?
- if current_user.exists?
- if current_user.any?
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `exists?' for #<User:0x00007fd68f4067b8>
undefined method `any?' for #<User:0x00007fd68f4067b8>
```

So only the first 2 work. Why? Is there any difference in performance of:

```
- if current_user
vs
- if current_user.present?
```

and

```
- if current_user.name
vs
- if current_user.name.present?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: The post is about collections, but you are trying to check it on the instance - not a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call methods on objects you have to know what you are doing.

```
current_user.present?
```

Here you call a method called `present?` on the object `current_user`. This works because method `present?` is defined on this object. When you do

```
current_user.exists?
```

you expect `current_user` to respond to a method called `exists?`. But it does not, thus error.

You mixed up a few things into this single question.

Only call methods on an object if you are sure it responds to this method.

Difference between `if current_user` vs `if current_user.present?` is implicit vs explicit check for object truthiness. See, in Ruby, everything except for `false` and `nil` is truthy. So `if current_user` means if `current_user` is anything except for `nil` or `false` then proceed. You rely on expression evaluation, while in `current_user.present?` you rely explicitly on a return value from a method call (`present?`).

I suggest you

- always go with explicit because it reads better;
- read about objects and methods in Ruby.

Comment: From my understanding, nil? blank? present? apply to everything and exists? any? empty? apply to records. But doesn't current_user of Devise return a User record, just as @user returns a record?

Comment: @JunDalisay to check whether an object respond to a method you can do `your_object.respond_to?(:method_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

current_user returns the current user if the current user is present. So it could return nil.

`nil.present?` will evaluate to `false`
`<User:0x00007fd68f4067b8>#present?` will evaluate to `true`

Neither of these is significantly less performant than the other

`any?` doesn't work because user is not Enumerable

`exists?` doesn't work because the `User` class doesn't have a method called `exists?` You could be thinking of the class method which checks if a given record exists.

using `current_user.name` runs the risk of calling `nil.name` when there is no user. Your best bet is to use `current_user` or `current_user.present?`

Answer (score -1):

For condition checking both are same. `current_user` will return `user` object or `nil` and `cuurent_user.present?` will return `boolean`.

I would suggest to use `current_user` not the `current_user.present?`.