# Undefined method exists? for Draper::CollectionDecorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, draper

I am trying to implement the Draper gem for my Rails project and having trouble getting it to work.  I'm getting the error message:

**undefined method `exists?' for #Draper::CollectionDecorator:0x000055b625da7a10>**

The error seems to be coming up from a partial I'm rendering on my index view.  The partial is calling "@accounts.exists?" which is where the error is happening.  If I remove the call to the partial my decorator works fine.  I have a feeling I need to use a delegate command for this but I'm not sure.  I am fairly new to Rails and just starting to explore some of the helpful gems out there. I'm hoping someone could take a look at my code and point me in the right direction to get past this error. Thanks! :)

---

**Model: Account.rb**

```
# An account which will store many transactions and belongs to one user
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum: 2 }
  validates :starting_balance, presence: true
  validates :last_four, length: { maximum: 4 }

  # validates_associated :transactions

  after_create :create_initial_transaction

  def create_initial_transaction
    update(current_balance: 0.00)
    # rubocop:disable Metrics/LineLength
    Transaction.create(trx_type: 'credit', trx_date: Time.current, account_id: id, description: 'Starting Balance', amount: starting_balance)
    # rubocop:enable Metrics/LineLength
  end
end
```

**Controller: accounts_controller.rb**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_account, only: %i[show edit update destroy activate deactivate]

  # GET /accounts
  # GET /accounts.json
  def index
    @accounts = current_user.accounts.where(active: true).order('created_at ASC')
    @accounts = @accounts.decorate
  end

  def inactive
    @accounts = current_user.accounts.where(active: false).order('created_at ASC')
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_account
    @account = current_user.accounts.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:name, :starting_balance, :current_balance, :last_four, :active, :user_id)
  end
end
```

**Decorator: account_decorator.rb**

```
class AccountDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  decorates_finders
  decorates_association :user
  delegate_all

  def last_four_formatted
    last_four.present? ? ' ( ... ' + last_four.to_s + ')' : nil
  end
end
```

**View: accounts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "shared/pagetitle", locals: { page_model: "account", description: "Accounts" } %>

<!-- Render the message if no accounts exist -->
<%= render partial: "accounts/noaccounts", locals: { description: "It looks like you don't have any accounts added. To add an account, click the add account button at the top of the page :)" } %>

<div class="row" id="accounts">
  <%= render partial: "accounts/account", collection: @accounts %>
</div>
```

**View Partial: accounts/_noaccounts.html.erb**

```
<% if !@accounts.exists? then %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2">
      <div class="card ob-card-gradient ob-account-card">
        <div class="card-content ob-text-primary">
          <span class="card-title">Welcome to mysite!</span>
          <div class="row">
            <br />
            <div class="col s1"><i class="material-icons valign-wrapper">account_balance</i></div>
            <div class="col s11">
            <%= description %></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the draper gem, but you are attempting to call `exists?` on what looks like a collection of objects, not on an ActiveRecord object. And since `exists?` is [defined in ActiveRecord](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F), you're not going to be able to do that.

You can probably safely change this line:

```
<% if !@accounts.exists? then %>
```

to:

```
<% if @accounts.empty? then %>
```

The `.empty?` method is [defined in multiple places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails), but the gist of it is if an object like a collection is empty then it will return true.

Comment: Wow, I changed my code and it works perfectly now.  I've been stumped on this for hours, so now I have a follow up question.  Before I tried using Draper, that bit of code (!@accounts.exists?) worked fine and behaved as I expected it to.  Any idea why?  Anyway, much thanks for the answer!

Comment: If `@accounts` was an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object (the type of object returned by something like `Account.where(foo: 'bar')`) then it will have the method `exists?` because it's an object created by ActiveRecord. When you call `decorate`, it returns a `Draper::CollectionDecorator` object, which is not created by ActiveRecord, so it does not have the method.

Comment: As a debugging tip you can call `object.methods` (e.g., `@accounts.methods`) in the console to list the methods that are available on that object. To skip listing all the standard Ruby methods that are applied to all objects you can call `@accounts.methods - Object.methods` and it will provide a more succinct list of methods. In your case, you'll see that `@accounts` does not have a `.exists?` method, but `Account.all.methods - Object.methods` will include `exists?(*conditions) Account::ActiveRecord_Relation (ActiveRecord::FinderMethods)`, telling you the method exists AND where to find it.