# Ruby rails object is nil, yet controller logic acting as if object is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have an an object `Search` with a method `listings` that returns an array of hashes if there are search results, otherwise it returns an empty array.  In the event there is any empty array, I need to skip some code and go straight to the show page.  I've tried `object.nil?` `object.empty?` `object.present?` all with the same outcome....the object which is supposed to be nil is treated as non-nil.

Controller code:

```
def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @results = @search.listings
    if @results.last.present?
      if @results.last[0] == "p" || @results.last[0] == "s" || @results.last[0] == "d"
        p "@results.pop is either p, s, or d"
        @sort_column = @results.pop
        @grade = @sort_column.gsub(/[^0-9,.]/, "") unless @results.last[0] == "d"
      end
    end
  end
```

show action results in

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #21):

19        p "@results.pop is either p, s, or d"
20        @sort_column = @results.pop
21        @grade = @sort_column.gsub(/[^0-9,.]/, "") unless @results.last[0] == "d"
22      end
23    end
24  end
```

but, the server interface verifies that @results.last is nil:

```
>>  @results
=> []
>>  @results.last
=> nil
>>  @results.last.present?
=> false
>>  @results.last[0]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/tomb/Projects/schoolsparrow/app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:21:in `show'
>>
```

I'm at a loss as to how to logic is getting past the `results.last.present?` when `results.last` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing to see whether or not your array has any values in it, try:

```
@results.any?
```

An empty array is not nil, which is why your checks are failing.

EDIT:

[A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I tried results.any? but still failing.  Note I'm calling .present? not on the array, but on array.last.

Comment: No worries - you say it's still failing, how so? If @results is an empty array then @results.any? will return false (indicating it's empty), and if it has results then it will return true

Comment: Its failing by somehow making it it to line 21 where results.last[0] flips an error because results.last is nil.  How is it getting past results.last.present?

Comment: Looks like you need to either wrap up line 21 in a conditional (if @results.any?), or add a check before line 21 which will cancel the method (return unless @results.any?)

Comment: If you don't want any more code to execute if there are no more results then it's best to: `return unless @results.any?`

Comment: `last` must return `nil` based on https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html#method-i-last. Is your `@search.listings` an `ActiveRecord` relationship ?, or is your `Search` class something else, like a custom class using Solr or some other search/indexing mechanism ?, that could be overwriting some stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the question @fanta, I went into Search to answer your question and discovered the problem.  `@results` will return one result due to an indicator that I pass into the array, even if there are no listings, so initially `@results` is not `nil`, its only when I call `.pop` that the `@results` become `nil`.  Instead of `.present?` I need to have a conditional `if @results.count > 1`

Comment: @tomb glad you found the solution. keep on rocking!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check your condition on `@results.present?` and not `@results.last.present?`.

`@results.last` would throw a `NoMethodError` if `@result` is `nil`

Answer (score 0):

To check if an array has elements use `.any?` or its opposite twin `.empty?`:

```
irb(main):006:0> [].empty?
=> true
irb(main):007:0> [].any?
=> false
```

`.present?` and `.presence` work on arrays but they are really more idiomatically correct for hashes like the params.

```
def show
  @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  @results = @search.listings
  if @results.any? && ['p', 's', 'd'].include?(@results.last[0])
    p "@results.pop is either p, s, or d"
    @sort_column = @results.pop
    @grade = @sort_column.gsub(/[^0-9,.]/, "") unless @results.last[0] == "d"
  end
end
```