# Equivalent of .presence in Python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, validation, language-comparisons

So, I've been using Ruby on Rails for some time, and I'm wondering if there is something like `.presence` in Python/Django.

**Presence** returns the receiver if it is present otherwise returns `nil`.

**object.presence** is equivalent to:

```
object.present? ? object : nil
```

For example, something like:

```
state   = params[:state]   if params[:state].present?
country = params[:country] if params[:country].present?
region  = state || country || 'US'
becomes

region = params[:state].presence || params[:country].presence || 'US'
```

Anthony

Comment: `d = {'foo': 'asad', 'bar': 'asdfsfs'}; d.get('foo'); d.get('foobar')`. The former will return `asad` and the latter will return `None`

Comment: Describe the purpose of the function here. And have you checked the list of Python built-ins?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, `presence` and `present?` are not built-in Ruby methods; they're [defined by Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence).

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, becase python's truthiness criteria is the same as rails' `present?`. In ruby, only nil and false are "falsey" whereas in Python, empty strings/arrays/objects are also "falsey" (see https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html). So, you could just say `params = {"state": "", "country": ""}; result = params.get("state") or params.get("country") or "US"` and result would equal "US".

Comment: For the sake of clarity, this question provides an overview of `present?`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663389/1779477

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, you can achieve this by doing the following, assuming `params` is a `dict`:

```
state = params.get('state')
country = params.get('country')
region = 'US' if (state and country) else None
```

The method `dict.get(key)` will return the value associated to the key that has been passed. If no such key exists, it returns `None`.

If you need to replace the empty values with actual empty strings, you may do this instead:

```
state = params.get('state', '')
country = params.get('country', '')
region = 'US' if (state and country) else ''
```

Overall, the "Pythonic" way of doing this is to use a Form:

```
class Address(Model):
    state = ...
    country = ...
    region = ...

AddressForm = modelform_factory(Address)

#inside view
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            address = form.save(commit=False)
            address.region = 'US' if address.state and address.country
            address.save()
```

By creating a custom AddressForm class you can do this processing automatically on the instance before saving it. This is the precise role of Form classes.

Comment: Disclaimer, I haven't used Django in a while and I have based this answer by reading the documentation, without actually testing this.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

The ruby version translated to python is roughly (except for truthiness edge cases):

```
region = params.get('state') or params.get('country') or 'US'
```

sleblancs answer instead sets the region to 'US' if state and country is set. Completely different.