# Is there a benefit to Rails' ".present?" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, is there a difference between:

```
if obj
  # ...
end
```

and:

```
if obj.present?
  # ...
end
```

It seems they do the same thing and not using `.present?` would help keep the line of code shorter and potentially cleaner. I understand that `.present?` is the opposite of `blank?` but should we always be using it when trying to determine if an object is "truthy" or not?

Is there a performance difference of some kind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Maybe, but I don't really need to know the difference between nil, empty, blank, present. I'm simply asking if it's worth calling `.present?` on an object when testing for truthiness.

Comment: There is a performance cost to `present?` since adds a additional layer of calls, wether or not its significant is something you can test [with a benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html). But I do find that Rails noobs use it far too much - especially in cases where you are just checking if a variable is defined (not nil).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `#present?` method does a bit more in that it also returns false if the string was a real but empty string (i.e. `""`)

Which is useful as your forms might return empty strings instead of `nil`s.

You can also use `#presence` which is a useful way of returning the value only if the value is `#present?`

```
name = params[:name].presence || 'ardavis'
```

The above wouldn't work if `params[:name]` was an empty string and you didn't use `#presence`

Comment: But if I know my object is not a string then there's no real need for `.present?`, right? If I did `obj = MyModel.find(some_id)` then I know it's either nil or an instance of MyModel, right?

Comment: @ardavis `find` will never return `nil` (`find_by` will though). If `find` fails it will raise `ActiveRecord::ResourceNotFound`

Comment: Sorry, bad example. But yes, that's true.

Comment: Yes, if I'm doing `my_model = MyModel.find_by(id: some_id)` I pretty much never use `my_model.present?` so I agree with you there. Note that `#present?` also is useful (hoiwever) for empy arrays, empty hashes, and even `ActiveRecord::Relation` as in `User.where(last_name: 'Moussolini').present?`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 7):

They don't do the same thing at all.

In Ruby everything except `nil` and `false` are truthy. This is amazingly sane compared to the type casting schenigans in other popular dynamic languages.

```
irb(main):003:0> !!""
(irb):3: warning: string literal in condition
=> true
irb(main):004:0> !!0
=> true
irb(main):005:0> !![]
=> true
irb(main):006:0> !!{}
=> true
irb(main):007:0> !!Object.new
=> true
irb(main):008:0> !!nil
=> false
irb(main):009:0> !!false
=> false
```

`present?` and `presence` are a part of ActiveSupport which can be used to test for nil and false but are actually more useful when dealing with user input:

```
irb(main):010:0> "".present?
=> false
irb(main):011:0> [].present?
=> false
irb(main):012:0> {}.present?
=> false
```

`present?` and `presence` are widely overused by Rails beginners that don't bother to learn Ruby first. Just use implicit truth checks (`if foo`) or `foo.nil?` if you just want to check if an argument is sent or not or if a variable is set.

And while `.present?` can be used on ActiveRecord collections but there are more idiomatically correct choices such as `any?` and `none?`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with string only checking if the attribute or object exists will return true, but present method will return false.

Here are some examples:

```
# Double negation return the boolean value
!!""
=> true


"".present?
=> false

" ".present?
=> false

[].present?
=> false

nil.present?
=> false

true.present?
=> true

false.present?
=> false

{}.present?
=> false

person = {:firstName => "John", :lastName => "Doe"}
person.present?
=> true

5.present?
=> true
```