# Rails - !arr&.any? = arr&.empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, I want to check if an array is empty(arr = []).

```
!arr&.any? 
arr&.empty?
```

Which is more correct?

Comment: Your first sentence is clear but you have confused some readers about what you want to do by your use of the Safe Navigation operator. Perhaps you could add an example (including the desired result) to clarify your question. More generally, why did you choose to use the Safe Navigation operator?

Comment: I think arr.empty? is correct to check if the array is empty and arr.any? is correct to check if the array is not empty.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the following Ruby:

```
[1, 2].any? => true
[nil, false].any? => false
[nil, nil].any? => false

[1, 2].empty? => false
[nil, nil].empty? => false
```

[Enumerable#any?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F) is a method that asks "is there anything in this collection that’s true?" In Ruby, the existence of an object is considered true; so calling `#any?` without a block is saying is there something that’s not nil or false in this collection?.

For more information see "[any? != ! empty?](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/any-empty)"

Comment: "...the existence of an object is considered true..." requires clarification. You might tweak your example by writing `[nil, false].any? => false`.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby on Rails I would use [`blank?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F). From the docs:

> An object is blank if it's false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, nil, '', ' ', [], {}, and false are all blank.

```
array = []
array.blank? 
#=> true
```

Note that `blank?` only works in Ruby on Rails, not in plain Ruby and that it has a slightly different behavior then `empty?`. Have a look at this [comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26877095/2483313) about the responses or errors you might get from the different methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check that `arr` contains no elements then `arr.empty?` is correct.

If you want to also accept `nil` or `false` as empty then `!arr || arr.empty?` is correct. In Ruby on Rails you can use [`arr.blank?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) instead.

`arr&.empty?` does the opposite of what you intend. `nil&.empty?` is *false* when you want the result from `nil` to be true. If `arr` is `nil` the safe navigation operator `&.` will return `nil`. [Rubocop](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will catch this with [Lint/SafeNavigationWithEmpty](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_lint/#lintsafenavigationwithempty).

Comment: The OP’s first sentence makes clear what is desired (especially “`arr = []`”). You and others giving answers refer to `nil`, `false`, `blank`, but none of that is relevant. I upvoted for your first sentence but suggest that you remove the “if clause” in that sentence, explain why you think ‘empty?` is preferred to alternatives and ditch the rest.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sometimes what people ask for and what they need are not quite the same. They say they're checking for `[]` but they're using safe navigation, so it seems they want `nil` to be empty. Rails offers `blank?` to handle that. `arr&.empty?` is clearly incorrect and that needed to be addressed (I got bit by this myself just recently). Now they have options and they can decide which is appropriate, we don't have enough context to decide for them.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to determine if an array `arr` is empty; that is, if `arr` equals the empty array `[]`. Here are some ways of doing that<sup>1</sup>:

```
arr == []
arr.size == 0
arr.empty?
```

Of these, `arr.empty?` is normally the method of choice, if for no other reason than it reads best.

When choosing one method among several that work you should consider what would happen if there were a bug in your code resulting in `arr` holding an object that is not an array. In particular, many bugs could result in `arr` holding `nil`. Should that occur `arr == []` is problematic because it would return `false` and merrily carry on, masking the bug from detection at that point.

`nil.size == 0` and `nil.empty?` both raise exceptions (because `nil` does not have a method `size` or `empty?`), which is what you want.

You certainly do not want to use the Safe Navigation operator as it would serve only to mask errors when `arr` is `nil`:

```
arr = nil
arr&.size
  #=> nil
arr&.empty?
  #=> nil
```

Lastly `arr.size == 0` has the weakness that the coder may inadvertently write `arr.size = 0`, particularly if playing *Call of Duty* while coding (though `arr.size.zero?` would be good practice as it overcomes that potential problem).

To sum up, it is difficult to find an argument for using something other than `arr.empty?` to determine if an array is empty.

<sup>1 The question suggests the use of the method [Array#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-any-3F). That doc references [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), which makes clear that, for example, `[nil].any?` returns `false`, yet `[nil]` is not empty. Hence, `any?` cannot be used to determine if an array is empty.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged the question with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), I'm adding an answer based upon an active record collection.

Since everything other than `nil` and `false` is considered truthy. For active record collections this means that the behaviour would be the same for `records.any?` and `!records.empty?`. This is also visible when looking at [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L277-L280)
 for `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

> ```
> # Returns true if there are any records.
> def any?
>   return super if block_given?
>   !empty?
> end
> ```

So assuming there is no block given and you're working with an `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
User.active.any?
# results in the same result as
!User.active.empty?
```

Comment: While this is true, the subtle difference in behavior between `ActiveRecord::Relation#any?` and `Enumerable#any?` invites confusion. It's very common to swap Relations for Arrays and other Enumerables. I would recommend steering away from using `any?` to mean `!empty?` and perhaps use `present?`.

Comment: I agree, that there is a subtle difference. However, there is also a subtle difference between `any?` and `present?` for `ActiveRecord::Relation`. `any?` will use a count query if the records aren't loaded yet, but doesn't if the collection is already loaded. `present?` will load the full collection if not already loaded instead of using a count query. I do understand that this answer doesn't fully fit, since OP specifically asked about arrays. However I feel the need to still mention it, since it's related to the [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag.

Comment: For those interested in the differences between `ActiveRecord::Relation` query methods, I've listed the differences in a [comment under an Rails style guide issue](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rails-style-guide/issues/232#issuecomment-425848425).